# Redirect to other page (Front-end) - Error code: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have problem with redirecting to other page, and resulting to this error:
[image: Error - STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION]

I'm encountering this when I'm trying to redirect to other page in front-end script:

```
window.localStorage.setItem('img1', JSON.stringify({img_data}))
window.location.replace("/visitor/login");
```

Is there problem in setting data in localstorage then redirecting to other page?

I have a route in my server for "/visitor/login":

```
app.get("/visitor/login", (req, res) => {
    res.render("./Visitor Module/login");
})
```

Comment: Everything I can find when I google that error seems to indicate that this is not a problem with specific code, but more with Chrome itself. The solutions I see being suggested range from renaming the browser exe file, over re-installing the browser, to switching to a different browser altogether ...

Comment: I am also facing this issue. it's working fine in macOS but getting error in windows with any browser

Comment: You ever managed to find a solution to this? It's happening consistently on an app I'm working with (in dev) when redirecting back from an OAuth flow.

Comment: @gr33nTHumB did you manage to find a reason for this crash?

Comment: @marcus nope. I believe it was fixed in Chrome itself